# Is there a way to import iam-roles in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to import existing aws resource iam-role 'DEVOPS' to my terraform management.

Though the resorce exists i get the following error -

Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object

While attempting to import an existing object to
aws_iam_role.okta_devops_role, the provider detected that no object exists
with the given id. Only pre-existing objects can be imported; check that the
id is correct and that it is associated with the provider's configured region
or endpoint, or use "terraform apply" to create a new remote object for this
resource.

I created empty resource -> aws_iam_role.devops_role in my main.tf

Comment: It is helpful to post the command that you are attempting to run, so that we can see if there are syntax errors...

Comment: I believe the error comes from the name of your tf resource,which is different than the name of your role. You have `aws_iam_role.okta_devops_role` and you should be able to import by doing what @eatsfood stated. I believe it would be something like `terraform import aws_iam_role.okta_devops_role DEVOPS` assuming that DEVOPS is the name of the role that you want to import

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to import an existing IAM role resource by doing the following:

1. Create the stub for the resource in your `main.tf` like this:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "DEVOPS" {
  # stub
}
```

2. Run the import command:

```
terraform import aws_iam_role.DEVOPS DEVOPS
```

3. When that is complete, show the resource and update the resource stub you
   created in step 1:

```
terraform show
```

Here is a [link to the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role).

Answer (score 0):

just as a complementary solution. In case you have defined your `aws_iam_role` inside a module, you may need to add two prefixes to the `terraform import` command. One way to find the correct resource name from the module is by using the `terraform plan` command.

For example, this `aws_iam_role` resource that is inside a module

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "reports_role" {
  name = "${var.environment}_reports_role"

  inline_policy {
    name = "${var.environment}_s3_access_policy"
    policy = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/s3_access_policy.json", {
      bucket_name = var.bucket_name
    })
  }
}
```

I get the following error when trying to deploy it for the `dev` overlay (environment):

> ╷ │ Error: error creating IAM Role (prod_reports_role):
> EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name prod_reports_role already exists.
> │     status code: 409, request id: *******************
> │  │   with module.aws_role.aws_iam_role.reports_role, │   on
> ../../modules/authorization/roles/role.tf line 1, in resource
> "aws_iam_role" "reports_role": │    1: resource "aws_iam_role"
> "reports_role" { │  ╵

After using the `terraform plan` command I can see its name and import it. As you can see I have to add `module.aws_role` before the `aws_iam_role.reports_role`.

```
terraform import module.aws_role.aws_iam_role.reports_role dev_reports_role
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting Terraform v1.5.0 you can use an `import` block to import IAM Roles using the name:

```
import {
  to = aws_iam_role.devops
  id = "DEVOPS"
}
```

Link to documentation [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role#import) (scroll to the Import block at the bottom).

Answer (score -4):

There is no way for importing the existing resources which are not provisioned via terraform.

As terraform do refer to the resource via terraform state file and detects the configuration drift

Still, you can give a try to:-

```
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer#use-with-aws
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Terraform does have import functionality.